# How to change MobileFirst 8 server URL dynamically from client (Mobile Application)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am working on ionic 3 with MobileFirst 8.x in it. To connect server I have configured URL in config.xml file.

**Is there any way to change server URL dynamically while using application?**

URL change occurs only once and after that we will connect the services which are secure under any scopes.

```
MobileFirst server version :- 8.0.0.00-20170911-123510
MobileFirst Cordova(plugin) version :- 8.0.2017102403
```

I can see that provision was there in MobileFirst 7.x :-
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/

Comment: Help me understand what you're trying to do please.  Are you wanting to use Direct Update to change the targeted server that the application contacts when it starts?  Also, the element in config.xml that your targeting is <mfp:server runtime="mfp" url="http://10.0.0.1:9080" />, correct?

Comment: I want like this https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the `WL.App.setServerURL` to achieve this. Usage details [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/api/client-side-api/javascript/client/)

You have not mentioned why you intend to use the API. This API comes handy in development environments. For example, switching between dev or staging server instances.

Important points to note:

1) As this API points the client application to a new server, client id associated with the earlier server is reset. The application will register fresh to the new server.

2) Authentication contexts created by the earlier server is reset. You will be challenged again by the new server.

You should use this API judiciously and with caution.

Comment: WL.App.setServerURL save url in some local storage of device, so next application startup it stay changed url, Is there any way to reset url (to config.xml url) on next application startup.

Comment: No. This is not a temporary configuration.